# Multiple travelling salesman problem ant colony optimization

Tags: python, traveling-salesman

how to divide 2 routes to find the shortest distance on Multiple traveling salesman problem ant colony optimization using python? where the result of the route must start from the starting city.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Some code and an input/output example would help to understand what you are trying to do